# Clean up old Domain Name for Nodes in Puppet Dashboard

Tags: puppet, facter, puppet-dashboard

I changed the domain name for some servers, i.e. web1.foo.com to web1.baz.com. In my Puppet Dashboard, I see two entries now for the same server.

I can destroy a node with something like `rake node:fast_del name=web1.foo.com` which seems to work (the web interface destroy doesn't work, see http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6828) but only temporarily, eventually the old domain comes back. I checked `facter` on the host and I don't see any sign of the old domain in there, any idea why the old domain comes back?

Comment: Just realized that maybe the puppet daemon has been running since before the domain name change, and the new domain comes from `puppet agent --test`. I thought this test signaled the daemon instead of running its own instance, but maybe that is not the case. Testing this now....

Comment: puppet agent --test does not signal the daemon. puppet kick does however ... if you have it configured to work.

Comment: Does destroying a node from the Dashboard now works? Last time I checked it did (using 1.2.10) and issue 6828 is closed. However there was no domain change.

Comment: Did signaling the agent made duplicates not reappear?